# Deletar vários elementos banco de dados linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Eu tenho uma *action* `[GET] delete` na minha WebApi.

Ela remove **um** elemento, mas gostaria que ele removesse **todos** os elementos que possuem um código determinado.

Como posso alterar meu código para remover todos?

Meu Código:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("delete/{Con_codigo}")]
public HttpResponseMessage delete(int Con_codigo)
{
    try
    {
        var condel = bdprincipalEntities.Contatos
                         .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Con_codigo == Con_codigo);

        bdprincipalEntities.Contatos.Remove(condel);
        bdprincipalEntities.SaveChanges();

        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

Sei que a minha busca me retorna apenas o primeiro. Pensei em alterar de `FirstOrDefault` para `Select`, porém ele me da a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Não é possível converter de "System.linq.IQueryable para SoftluxApi.Models.Contatos
>
> Atualização:

O método acima acaba removendo todos os contatos, como eu estava pedindo, então estou mudando a pergunta para, porque mesmo com o `FirstOrDefault` ele remove vários elementos do banco de dados?

Comment: Uma dica importante: Não mude o foco da sua pergunta depois de postá-la, principalmente se a publicação já recebeu respostas. Você var acabar fazendo com que sua pergunta fique confusa e que os respondedores percam o trabalho que tiveram pra escrever uma resposta. Se você tiver uma dúvida diferente e que seja pertinente de perguntar aqui, abra uma nova pergunta, não existe limite para postagens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de qualquer coisa eu preciso dizer ter um endpoint GET para remover um recurso não faz o mínimo sentido semanticamente.

---

Se você está usando EF 6.0 ou uma versão mais recente, pode usar o método [`RemoveRange`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.removerange?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) e simplificar o código.

```
bdprincipalEntities.Contatos.RemoveRange(
    bdprincipalEntities.Contatos.Where(x => x.Con_codigo == Con_codigo));
```

Caso use uma versão mais antiga, vai precisar buscar todas as entidades e depois excluí-las uma a uma.

```
var contatos = bdprincipalEntities.Contatos.Where(x => x.Con_codigo == Con_codigo);

foreach(var contato in contatos)
    bdprincipalEntities.Contatos.Remove(contato);

bdprincipalEntities.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Eu consigo utilizar o método RemoveRange, mas não sabia que podia fazer consultas dessa maneira, sou novo na linguagem, muito obrigado pela resposta, mas pode tirar outra duvida minha antes de eu aceitar sua resposta?  porque mesmo com o FirstOrDefault ele remove vários elementos do banco de dados?

Comment: @JeffHenrique Não tenho como responder sem saber mais detalhes. Mas provavelmente é porque a coluna `Con_codigo` tem valores repetidos e o SQL gerado está usando este valor na clausula where.

Comment: Sim, tem valores repetidos, pois é necessário pro projeto, mas muito obg, ajudou mt

Comment: Em relação ao endpoint GET, eu peguei o projeto e já estava assim antes, mas vou conversar aqui sobre não fazer sentido semanticamente